# SwiftUI DatePicker with a choice between today and tomorrow

Tags: date, swiftui, datepicker

I'm trying to make a DatePicker with a choice between today and tomorrow. Two buttons to switch Date Range.

How to make today range? i. e. Now -> End of the day

How to make tomorrow range? i. e. Start of the next day -> End of the next day

and How to make DatePicker respond to this changes?

What selection should I pick to bind it to DatePicker(I mean which date), depend on Range?

What I already did:

```
   VStack { 
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Button("Today") {
                    //switch to today range
                }
                Spacer()
                Button("Tomorrow") {
                    //switch to tommorow range
                }
                Spacer()
            }
            
            DatePicker("Delivery Time", selection: $date, in: tommorowRange, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
                .labelsHidden()
                .datePickerStyle(.wheel)
                .frame(width: 200, height: 150)
                .clipped()
                .padding()
}
```

Date Ranges: (not correct)

```
var todayRange: ClosedRange<Date> {
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    var endComponents = DateComponents()
    endComponents.day = 1

    let endDate = calendar.date(byAdding: endComponents, to: Date.now)!
    return Date.now ... endDate
}

var tommorowRange: ClosedRange<Date> {
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    var startComponents = DateComponents()
    startComponents.day = 2
    var endComponents = DateComponents()
    endComponents.day = 1

    let startDate = calendar.date(byAdding: startComponents, to: Date.now)!
    let endDate = calendar.date(byAdding: endComponents, to: startDate)!
    return startDate ... endDate
}
```

How it should look:

[image: Example pic]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `DatePicker` with `displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute` and make the `Today` and `Tomorrow` `Button`s that just change the date components relevant to a `date`.

```
struct CustomDatePicker: View {
    @State var date: Date = .now
    @State var showPicker: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            showPicker.toggle()
        } label: {
            Text(date, format:.dateTime)
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showPicker) {
            VStack{
                HStack{
                    Spacer()
                    //Today Button
                    Button {
                        //Components for date for today
                        var todayComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year,.month,.day,.calendar], from: Date())
                        //Components for time from the `date` that is affected by the picker
                        let pickTime = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute,.timeZone], from: date)
                        //Combine the components
                        todayComponents.hour = pickTime.hour
                        todayComponents.minute = pickTime.minute
                        todayComponents.timeZone = pickTime.timeZone
                        //Set the new date
                        date = Calendar.current.date(from: todayComponents)!
                    } label: {
                        Text("Today")
                         //Change color depending on date
                         .foregroundColor(Calendar.current.isDateInToday(date) ? Color.accentColor : Color.gray)
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    //Tomorrow Button
                    Button {
                        //Tomorrow's date
                        let tomorrow = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: .now)!
                        //Components for the date
                        var tomorrowComp = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year,.month,.day,.calendar], from: tomorrow)
                        //Components for the time
                        let pickTime = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute,.timeZone], from: date)
                        //Combine
                        tomorrowComp.hour = pickTime.hour
                        tomorrowComp.minute = pickTime.minute
                        tomorrowComp.timeZone = pickTime.timeZone
                        //Set the new date
                        date = Calendar.current.date(from: tomorrowComp)!
                    } label: {
                        Text("Tomorrow")
                    }
                    //Change color depending on date
                     .foregroundColor(Calendar.current.isDateInTomorrow(date) ? Color.accentColor : Color.gray)
                    Spacer()
                }
                DatePicker("date", selection: $date, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute).datePickerStyle(.wheel)
            }.presentationDetents([.medium])
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply add another `DatePicker` and switch between them via a toggle:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var todayDate: Date = .now
    @State var tomorrowDate: Date = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: .now)!)

    var todayRange: ClosedRange<Date> {
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        var endComponents = DateComponents()
        endComponents.day = 1

        let endDate = calendar.date(byAdding: endComponents, to: Date.now)!
        return Date.now ... endDate
    }

    var tomorrowRange: ClosedRange<Date> {
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        var startComponents = DateComponents()
        startComponents.day = 2
        var endComponents = DateComponents()
        endComponents.day = 1

        let correctStartDate = calendar.date(bySettingHour: 0, minute: 0, second: 0, of: .now)!
        let startDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: correctStartDate)!
        let endDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 2, to: correctStartDate)!
        return startDate ... endDate
    }

    @State var isTodayRange = true

    var body: some View {


        VStack { 
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Button("Today") {
                    withAnimation {
                        isTodayRange = true
                    }
                }
                .background(isTodayRange ? .red : .white)
                Spacer()
                Button("Tomorrow") {
                    withAnimation {
                        isTodayRange = false
                    }
                }
                .background(isTodayRange ? .white : .red)
                Spacer()
            }
            if isTodayRange {
                picker($todayDate, range: todayRange)
            } else {
                picker($tomorrowDate, range: tomorrowRange)
            }
        }
    }

    func picker(_ selection: Binding<Date>, range: ClosedRange<Date>) -> some View {
        DatePicker("Delivery Time", selection: selection, in: range, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
            .labelsHidden()
            .datePickerStyle(.wheel)
            .frame(width: 200, height: 150)
            .clipped()
            .padding()
    }
}
```